# How to remove an object from other keys in a dictionary [Objective-C]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, algorithm

I have an **NSMutableDictionary** as follows:

```
{ 0 = (1,5,6); 1 = (0,2,6,7); 2 = (1,7,8); 5 = (0,6,10,11); 6 = 
(0,1,5,7,11,12)};
```

in the format of **{NSNumber:NSMutableArray}**

I want to remove every **0** that is there in every key or the keys for the values of '0'. What is a way to do it?

The expected outcome is:

```
{ 0 = (1,5,6); 1 = (2,6,7); 2 = (1,7,8); 5 = (6,10,11); 6 = 
(1,5,7,11,12)};
```

I am looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: but the key 0 is not removed?

Comment: Loop through your values and remove the 0's from the arrays..

Comment: It can be considered. I am looking for both solutions.

Comment: Are all of the arrays already sorted?

Comment: No they are not.

Answer (score 1):

Use this assuming that your NSMutableArray is an `NSNumber` array, also the key 0 is removed in this improvement

## Improved

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
dict[@0] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@0,@10, nil];
dict[@1] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@0,@10, nil];
dict[@2] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@0,@7,@10, nil];

int valueToRemove = 0; //change this value for what you need
for (NSNumber * key in dict.allKeys) {
    if([key intValue] == valueToRemove) {dict[key] = nil;}
    dict[key] = [dict[key] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"intValue != %i",valueToRemove]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

## CONSOLE LOG

```
2017-07-28 02:18:21.257 ArrayProblemQuestion[76557:1576267] {
    1 =     (
        10
    );
     2 =     (
         7,
         10
     ); }
```

if you want to loop only for certain keys then

```
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@1,@3,@0, nil];
    for (NSNumber * key in [dict.allKeys filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"intValue IN %@",array]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",key);
    }
```

this will loop only for the keys contained in `array`

Hope this helps

Comment: What if my values were NSNumber?

Comment: @JacobBillings if you are using an dictionary of `[NSNumber:[NSNumber]]` then my code should work properly

Comment: I actually have NSNumber *value = @0. In future, it may change to some other value. You gave an elegant one! Almost there.

Comment: @JacobBillings did you try my answer?

Comment: It worked with 0 but I need to do it with an identifier like value.

Comment: @JacobBillings You need remove another value? this can be extended without any problems

Comment: Yes I may need to. I tried [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"intValue != value"], which doesn't work.

Comment: @JacobBillings Check my answer again a parameter was added, you can pass any value

Comment: +1. I wanted with NSNumber. I guess I got it. It's with "intValue != %@",valueToRemove]. Can you explain what the statement actually means?

Comment: Another question to be added, is it possible just to loop through keys that have items from key of the valuetoRemove instead of looping through all of the keys?

Comment: @JacobBillings yes that code must work, is a String with format, I am creating a predicate with string with format, you can further read about String with format basically what it does is replace the %@ by the object or replace the %i by the integer

Comment: @JacobBillings added a example of how loop over some keys only

Comment: `for (NSNumber * key in dict.allKeys)` is `allKeys` really better than simply doing `for (NSNumber * key in dict)` since a for each loop on a `NSDictionary` will iterates the keys?

Answer (score 0):

```
  // This is your input
NSMutableDictionary *dicMain = [NSMutableDictionary new];
dicMain[@"0"] = @[@1,@5,@6];
dicMain[@"1"] = @[@0,@2,@6,@7];
dicMain[@"2"] = @[@1,@7,@8];
dicMain[@"5"] = @[@0,@6,@10,@11];
dicMain[@"6"] = @[@0,@1,@5,@7,@11,@12];


    NSLog(@"%@",dicMain);
    // Remove key from Dic if its having 0
    if([[dicMain allKeys] containsObject:@"0"])
        [dicMain removeObjectForKey:@"0"];

   // Check each and every object into all key's that if its having 0 then it will remove 
    NSArray *aryAllKeys = [dicMain allKeys];
    for(NSString *strKey in aryAllKeys)
    {
        NSMutableArray *aryNewValue = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSArray *aryKeyValues = [dicMain objectForKey:strKey];
        for(NSString *str in aryKeyValues)
        {
            if([str intValue] != 0)
            {
                [aryNewValue addObject:str];
            }
        }
        // Set New array
        [dicMain setObject:aryNewValue forKey:strKey];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",dicMain);
```

The output of main Dic without removing 0:

**{
    1 =     (
        2,
        6,
        7
    );
    2 =     (
        1,
        7,
        8
    );
    5 =     (
        0,
        6,
        10,
        11
    );
    6 =     (
        0,
        1,
        5,
        7,
        11,
        12
    );
}**

After Removing 0:
**{
    1 =     (
        2,
        6,
        7
    );
    2 =     (
        1,
        7,
        8
    );
    5 =     (
        6,
        10,
        11
    );
    6 =     (
        1,
        5,
        7,
        11,
        12
    );
}**

Comment: All objects in the Array are in numbers not strings.

Comment: I put it for testing purpose. You can use the main login into your app. You will desire output.

Comment: `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],[NSNumber numberWithInt:6], nil];`   can be written like this:  `@[@1,@5,@6];`

Comment: @WilliamGP its for testing, Its input value, so questioner will get it from somewhere on server or other source. Anyway thanks for informing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this..

```
 [myDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber * _Nonnull key,
                                            NSMutableArray * _Nonnull array,
                                            BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    [array removeObject:@0];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below. This is improvement of other answer with key '0'.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
dict[@"0"] = @[@1,@5,@6];
dict[@"1"] = @[@0,@2,@6,@7];
dict[@"2"] = @[@1,@7,@8];
dict[@"5"] = @[@6,@10,@11];
dict[@"6"] = @[@0,@1,@5,@7,@11,@12];

int valueToRemove = 0; //change this value for what you need to remove

for (NSNumber * key in dict.allKeys) {    
    if([key intValue] == valueToRemove) {     
        dict[key] = [dict[key] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"intValue != %i",valueToRemove]];      
    }else{         
        dict[key] = [dict[key] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"intValue != %i",valueToRemove]];     
    }  
}

NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

And your expected output like this with key '0'.

```
{ 
0 =  ( 1, 5, 6 );
1 =   ( 2, 6, 7 );
2 =   ( 1, 7, 8 );
5 =   ( 6, 10, 11 );
6 =   ( 1, 5, 7, 11, 12 );
}
```